# Error importing FAISS on Lambda when a Numpy layer is added

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list, aws-lambda, faiss

I have FAISS running on a lambda layer, as soon as I add a layer containing Numpy it gives me this error, anyone know how to tackle this?

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_swigfaiss' from partially initialized module 'faiss' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/python/faiss/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
START RequestId: 33888d57-fe30-40ca-8250-b66878016a7c Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_swigfaiss' from partially initialized module 'faiss' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/python/faiss/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: 33888d57-fe30-40ca-8250-b66878016a7c
REPORT RequestId: 33888d57-fe30-40ca-8250-b66878016a7c  Duration: 2.12 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 99 MB  Init Duration: 1001.39 ms

Request ID
33888d57-fe30-40ca-8250-b66878016a7c
```

Ive tried containerizing FAISS and Numpy together but that hasnt helped.